# Simulated Reality : How is our level of existence described?

Tags: virtual-reality, taxonomy

If we are all living in a simulated reality with all of our sensory experiences being provided by a godlike computer, how would our version of reality be described?

It is a few "days" before I'm scheduled to strap back in and reincarnate for another 100 years of simulated corporeal life.

I'm flipping through the catalog of available existences, scratching off the high fantasy options with their complex magic-tolerant physical laws.  I'm also passing on the simplistic rapturous options like "fly on a dead cow", "eagle flying through endless sky" and the ever popular "eternal orgasm".

I want something engaging.  Something where I can be a scientist, exploring physical laws which are complex enough to remain challenging for a lifetime, yet not so complex that understanding the basics will exceed my cognitive capacity.

The opportunity to discover an undisclosed facet of the selected artificial reality and to feel proud of really making a difference... That is exactly what I'm looking for.

The only down side to living in the real world, as a post-scarcity immortal, is that there is nothing left to discover that human brains can understand, and no unsolved problems needing to be solved.

Eternal Utopia is boring.

...thus we escape into lesser lives in the artificial realms.

So finally, I turn to a page listing 4 fundamental forces and 23 chromosomes worth of IQ to explore them with.  It offers reasonably comfortable day to day existence, an average lifespan which fits my 100 year time budget, and lots of important scientific discoveries waiting to be wrestled out of hiding.

**What other high-science characteristics of our real world physical laws are worth mentioning in this catalog?**  Specifically those rules which would keep magic from working, yet still allow for the development of a high tech civilization.

Comment: It's called Virtual Reality #4116, part VI. Or Precarious Stimulating World 23, Full Option Edition. Or Wǔdài Shíguó. Or the Pleophonic Argosy (populary known as the Polnoglasnyy Mnozhestvo, Polnoglasnitsa for short). Or the Ithra Quotir. Or the Mathema GTL. Or the Eikonike Hyparxis (written Hyparxis Iconica in the editions of the catalog intended for old rich punters). Or the Ficta Veritas. Or the Metroless 3.11. Or Nausicaa, or maybe Arete, or even Calypso. Or the Titanomachic Quest. Or the Extermporaneous Exhilarating Exploration (X-3). Or the Phoenicean Option. Or the Poliorcetic Pursuit.

Comment: A big red EXIT sign seems like the classiest option to me. (But, this is why questions of "what do I name this?" are off-topic. How do we decide which answer(s) are correct when it's all personal opinion?)

Comment: @Cadence, agreed. This is off-topic in it's current form.  I started writing the question looking for characteristics of our specific set of physical laws, such as "four fundamental forces" which could be used in an advertisement for potential VR participant customers.  I got carried away with the creative wording on this one and didn't end up asking the in-topic question which I was aiming at.  I will try to fix it now.

Comment: Martin Rees, [*Just Six Numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_physical_constant#Martin_Rees's_Six_Numbers), 1999. $N \approx 10^{36}, \varepsilon \approx 0.007, \Omega \approx 0.3, \lambda \approx 0.7, Q \approx 10^{-5}, D = 3$.

Comment: Thanks @AlexP!  That is exactly what I was looking for.   If you make it an answer, I'll give you an up vote and check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Martin Rees, [*Just Six Numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_physical_constant#Martin_Rees's_Six_Numbers), 1999: $N \approx 10^{36}, \varepsilon \approx 0.007, \Omega \approx 0.3, \lambda \approx 0.7, Q \approx 10^{−5}, D=3$.

  (According to the Wikipedia description, $N$ the ratio of the fine structure constant to the gravitational coupling constant, $\varepsilon$ is the fraction of the mass of four protons that is released as energy when fused into a helium nucleus, $\Omega$ is the ratio of the actual density of the universe to the minimum density required for the universe to eventually collapse under its gravity, $\lambda$ is the ratio of the energy density of the universe to the critical density of the universe, $Q$ is the ratio of the energy required to break up and disperse an instance of the largest known structures in the universe to the energy equivalent to the rest mass of that structure, and finally $D$ is the number of macroscopic space dimensions.)

The entire Wikipedia article on [dimensionless physical constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_physical_constant) is interesting.